# Installing AWS CLI v2 through PIP on Windows

Tags: python, windows, installation, pip, aws-cli

Is it possible to install AWS CLI v2 through PIP on Windows?

[In the instructions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/install-cliv2-windows.html) the recommended way to install is via MSI, but I want to use PIP.

What if I install CLI [like given on Github](https://github.com/aws/aws-cli) in a Linux way:

```
python -m pip install awscli
```

Will it install v1 or v2 by default?

Comment: That's incorrect @metatoaster. AWS have not released version 2 to PyPi, and [refuse to do so](https://github.com/aws/aws-cli/issues/4947). Someone has put together a [third party package](https://pypi.org/project/awscliv2/) but I had problems with it and anyway it's a separate package. The [official PyPi package](https://pypi.org/project/awscli/) from `pip` will be the latest version 1 only.

Comment: @NeilG well, guess that general pip/PyPI usage note does not apply to this special snowflake of a package, what an annoying decision they've made, what a mess of a discussion thread, thanks for including this useful note.

Comment: That's right @metatoaster. They basically stopped updating the package. This is because corporate wisdom increases with age ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

pip install awscliv2

This single command should help you install awc cli v2

Comment: and why it is [not recognized](https://imgur.com/rYn7jOH) after this installation? should I add it to path manually?

Comment: @Suncatcher Because it installs as `awsv2`. You can add an alias on Linux so that one can use it as `aws`, not sure how to do that on windows though. Read more here: https://pypi.org/project/awscliv2/

Comment: @AnatolBivol `Because it installs as awsv2` is there any way to omit this behavior? MSI installer installs awscli correctly, with command name `aws`, why they didn't the same in pip? if I install only the v2, I want to access it through the unified name

Comment: @Suncatcher mostly because AWS does not create a pipy distribution for v2 cli and `awsv2` pypi has this note : "This is not an official AWS CLI v2 application". So you can't expect the same behavior as they are 2 different projects. Sadly we have to deal with this.

Comment: This should no be an accepted answer, in installs an unofficial build of AWS CLI V2 and assigns it a non-standard alias.

Answer (score 8):

For people would like to use `pipx` to isolate between environments, the url mentioned by [@FlyingTeller](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62423814/327074) `git+https://github.com/aws/aws-cli/tree/v2` does not work with `pipx`, instead you can try this:

```
pipx install git+https://github.com/aws/aws-cli.git@v2
```

After that you can see:

```
$ aws --version
aws-cli/2.4.17 Python/3.9.9 Linux/5.4.0-99-generic source/x86_64.ubuntu.20 prompt/off
```

Comment: Just to confirm, `pipx` here means `pip` or `pip3`, correct?

Comment: `pipx` is a wrapper for `pip` that creates and manages isolated virtual-environments per tool, that you don't have to activate: https://github.com/pypa/pipx

Comment: In case someone isn't very familiar with `pip` and its variants like `pipx`: this solution also work perfectly with `pip`. This should be an accepted answer.

Answer (score 4):

> Is it possible to install AWS CLI v2 through PIP on Windows?

No, not from pypi at least. The instructions from github you ahve linked to apply only to version 1.18 and also the [pypi project](https://pypi.org/project/awscli/) is at 1.18.

If you switch to the [v2 branch on github](https://github.com/aws/aws-cli/tree/v2), you will also notice that any reference to using pip for installing is gone, so the recommended way does indeed seem to only be to use the .msi installer.

This does not need to stop you per se, but since there is no whl file, installing with pip would mean to try to compile the source code, which is probably a pain on windows. you can still try it though, the command would be something like

```
python -m pip install git+https://github.com/aws/aws-cli/tree/v2
```